# error while calling function inside another function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, user-defined-functions, python-newspaper

I have function for `newspaper3k` which extract summary for given  url. Given as :-

```
def article_summary(row):
    url = row
    article = Article(url)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()
    text = article.summary
    return text
```

I have pandas dataframe with column named as `url`

```
url
https://www.xyssss.com/dddd
https://www.sbkaksbk.com/shshshs
https://www.ascbackkkc.com/asbbs
............
............
```

There is another function `main_code()` which runs perfectly fine and inside which Im using `article_summary`.I want to add both functions `article_summary` and `main_code()` into one function `final_code`.

Here is my code : 1st function as:-

```
def article_summary(row):
url = row
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()
text = article.summary
return text
```

Here is 2nd Function

```
def main_code():

article_data['article']=article_data['url'].apply(article_summary)
return article_data['articles']
```

When I have done:

```
def final_code():
    article_summary()
    main_code()
```

But `final_code()` not giving any output it shows as `TypeError: article_summary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'`

Answer (score 0):

Are those the actual URLs you're using? If so, they seem to be causing an `ArticleException`, I tested your code with some wikipedia pages and it works.

On that note, are you working with just one df? If not, it's probably a good idea to pass it as a variable to the function.

-----------------------------------Edit after comments----------------------------------------------------------------------
I think a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) on Python functions will be beneficial. That said, in regards to your specific question, calling a function the way you described it will make it run twice, which is not needed in this case. As I said earlier, you should pass the df as an argument to the function, here is a [tutorial on global vs local variables](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) and how to use them.

The error you're getting is because you should pass an argument 'row' to the function article_summary (please see functions tutorial).

Comment: How I can call both functions 'article_summary' and 'main_code' as once? As function 'article_summary' need to be called before 'main_code()'.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Edited my answer as well.